# How to read in strings into an array that is being used for a zip function in python?

Tags: python, list, parsing, memory, notifications

I am parsing an inventory log look like below and I want to read in the "data" into a list and pair them up with "info" for example:

```
+Hardware information  


Processor               : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 v2 @ 2.20GHz (24 cores/threads)

Memory                  : 81877MB

Controller Slot         : 0

BIOS                    : 3.0a 11/12/2013 3.1

IPMI FW rev             : 2.20

Canister firmware       :  2.2.26^M

Canister firmware date  :  Feb  5 2013 20:54:00^M
```

I need to pair up the info's with the data's for example 'BIOS' being the info and pair it with the data '3.0a 11/12/2013 3.1.

So using a zip function in I want to have the Info and the data side by side each other.I need to find a way to parse the inventory log and put the data into the data array(list) and pair them up to the correct info category (BIOS,Memory, etc,). Any ideas?

> ```
>  Info = ['IPMI FW rev','BIOS','Canister Firmware','Memory','Controller Slot']
>  Data = ['','','','','']
>         for I,D in zip(Info,Data):
>              print('{0}:{1}'.format(I,D))
> ```

Comment: You could consider using a dictionary

Comment: what about processor?

Comment: How could I implement a dictionary to this problem? @user2963623

Comment: @Intern_Bob check my answer. Use the items in `Info` as keys and the corresponding items in `Data` as the values.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
data = {}
with open('log.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    for line in file_obj:
        if ':' in line:
            pos = line.index(':')
            data[line[:pos].strip()] = line[pos+1:].strip()

for key in data: print key,':',data[x]
```

EDIT:

Like the comment below says this code assumes the file has a consistent structure. If there is any `:` before the separating`:`, this will fail.

Comment: if there are any `:` before the middle this will fail.